# Adding libraries in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I need to add libraries to my project, which are classes in directories, **it's not a *.jar file**.

I do it in the following way: `File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies -> +-> Jar or directories.`

But when I add required directory, I get the following result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What libraries do you try to use? It is common to download and use a Java library as a JAR file not as individual classes. Are you really sure you have the compiled class files in your directory and not the Java source files?

Comment: And you should consider to use a build tool like Maven or Gradle which handles the dependencies automatically for you.

Comment: @vanje I downloaded from https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java. Everything from this repository

Comment: This is the project's source code. You can not simply download the repository and include the directory as a library in IntelliJ. You first have to build the JARs. See section "Building from source" at the repo page or at the [project website](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/). But you should really use Maven in your own project and then you only have to include the dependency in your pom.xml. Of course, you can download the precompiled JAR from Maven Central but then you have to maintain the dependencies on your own.